# Bootstrap Drop down menu is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

its supposed to be drop down the menus  but its not working 
properly 
I can't figure it out what i did mistake to this code
Here is my code !!!

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Web Revert</a>
            </div>
            Menu Items 
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a herf="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                    <!-- Drop Down menu -->

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Founder Mamber</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            Right Aligns
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
</body>
```

help needed

Comment: You need to include enough code to duplicate the problem. (Your formatting is also broken.) I suggest using SO's [runnable snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) but you can also just use the code formatting you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried linking this first?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou its worked :) ... without CDN why its not working :/